# How to deploy gRPC back end on Google App Engine (Java)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, grpc

I want to use gRPC service as a back end deployed on GAE. But there is not much related information. Maximum what I found about gRPC and recent GAE versions is Google Cloud Platform [Blog](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2017/06/Google-App-Engine-standard-now-supports-Java-8.html), which tells that the recent major release brings full support of gRPC.

But I can't understand what means "full support" and how it can be actually achieved, because there are no detailed information, tutorials, samples.

So, what the additional requirements to use gRPC within GAE (either in standard or flexible environment)?

Comment: As of 2019, you still cannot run gRPC on App Engine. With gRPC & endpoints, you have few options available, which are `[compute engine, GKE, Kubernetes]`. `compute engine` option only allows you too run a single instance gRPC server, so it is not the ideal choice. https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/choose-endpoints-option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [reply](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/grpc-io/Ue2YBO8vetE) Dimitry received on Google Groups is valid. A useful document to be used in conjunction with the answer would be: "[Getting Started with gRPC on Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/get-started-grpc-compute-engine-docker)".

Answer (score 0):

Using gRPC with GAE Java 8 doesn't need anything special. Simply use the Netty transport and make sure to include netty-tcnative-boringssl-static like normal.

Comment: I still can't connect to gRPC server. A sample for this will be very helpful and can save a lot of time for people. Hope, you can provide it. Thank you, Eric!